# Oracle bulk insert missing audit entries

Tags: oracle, insert, audit, bulk

I've a Java/Hibernate/Spring application with oracle's audit (11g non-clustered) enabled, and it seems to be properly configured.

However, some entries are not being written to SYS.AUD$.

Here's my scenario:

I've a transaction which performs 8 inserts on Oracle, which are shown by hibernate's showsql, and are in fact written into the DB.

I've an AUDIT INSERT RULE BY ACCESS for the given table, and, I expected to see the 8 audit entries on Oracle's AUDIT for the given transaction, but i got only 4 inserts logged.
Sometimes, 5 entries are logged, and sometimes 3, tough.

I've managed to track down that this behavior is related to hibernate.jdbc.batch_size property value.

In the described scenario the value was set to 10.

If I change the value to 0 however, which disables jdbc batching, everything works just as expected and I always get the 8 insert audit logs.

I thought it could be a bug on ojdbc driver, but the bug persisted even after I upgraded to the latest version.

Disabling jdbc batch is not an option for me. Is it a bug ? Any thoughts on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is related to Direct-Path INSERT.  If you use FGA, (I think) the Direct-Path INSERT will not occur so that the audit always works.  I think you will have to choose one - Direct-Path INSERT or audit.

Why do you need jdbc batching?  What type of app is this?  Have you done performance testing with it on and off?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I´ll investigate that.
For your jdbc batch question: It's a really huge web application and 
I simply can't make a performance test on all its funcionalities to know whether they use or not jdbc batching. I know some places that do use, and would have a performance flaw.

Comment: I can't find how to disable it. Do you know any easy way? After reading documentation about Direct-Path INSERT I run ALTER DATABASE force logging, in the hope that every statement got logged even if I'm running on parallel mode (which I don't know yet), but still got the same error. I'll dig a bit harder tough

Comment: No, you can't override Oracle's native behavior.  You can't have it both ways (audit and direct path insert).  You need to pick one.   

... "and would have a performance flaw"  How do you know?  I thought you didn't do a real performance test?  Here is my educated guess after being a DBA for 20 years.  Your use of batching 5 - 10 rows will not be noticed in the app.  Of course, the only way to know is to test it.

Comment: Sorry, i guess I misexpressed myself. I can't find how to disable it, and tried to set the force logging parameter. I guess i don't need direct-path (tough i'll have to verify it). Can you help me disabling it? I'll consider disabling batch also, but, I would have to discuss it to other team members (and maybe CTO).

Comment: I've also posted on OTN and got one nice answer. Please, see if it helps your understanding of the problem https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10786744#10786744